# Remember me in REST using Spring security

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I need to create "Remember me"-provided REST service. My app should receive JSON with login data, authenticate user and make it possible for app to remember the user. I've written some code snippet with few mocked @RequestMapping's and simple Spring security config, and, however, application authenticates user (because of successfulAuthentication() Filter's method invocation). But when I'm trying to send request to the secured url even after login action, it returns 401 code. I know, this is quite obvious that new request creates a new session, but is there any way to perform "remember me" behaviour without sending login info in each Request's body? Here is some of my code:

```
package com.checkpoint.aimer.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

public class RestSecurityFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter{

    public RestSecurityFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager m) {
        super(url);
        this.setAuthenticationManager(m);
    }


    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        Authentication auth = this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("roman", "sawawluha"));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

        return auth;
    }
}
```

Security configuration:

```
package com.checkpoint.aimer.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public RestSecurityFilter restSecurity() throws Exception {
        RestSecurityFilter filter = new RestSecurityFilter("/auth/login_test", authenticationManagerBean());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService usr() {
        return new UserSecurityService();
    }

    @Override 
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {

                @Override
                public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        AuthenticationException arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Oops");

                }
            }).and()
            .addFilterBefore(restSecurity(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class )
            .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("key",usr()) ).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").anonymous()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth
            .userDetailsService(usr());
    }



}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remember me features are mostly implemented based on cookies. You can store some authentication token into cookie. I believe you can even use  Session Cookies for this.

BUT REMEMBER:

- You have to use HTTPS all the time
- Use [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly) cookie attribute all the time
- Use [Secure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) cookie attribute all the time

Because cookie is send to client with every request, you need to make sure it's send via secure channel, and not accessible to cross site attacks.

Comment: Do you mean - the server would create a `httpOnly` and `secure` cookie which will hold the access-token and then server set it to the browser? Then this cookie will be sent with each request, which solves the remember-me feature in REST and this remember-me would depend on the expiration of the cookie?

Comment: Token needs to expire on server. You can't rely on client to expire cookie.